# Rails find :include in a multi DB environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am making a site in RoR and I am inside a multi DB environment. By that, I mean that some of my models are linked to MSSQL tables, and some others are linked to MYSQL tables.

It works well for the most part, but when I use the 'include' option in a find method, I get a very weird mix of SQL. Let me show you an example:

```
[SELECT * FROM "viewInfoClient" WHERE ("viewInfoClient".`NoClient` IN (6044196,5000652,0204392)) ]
```

MSSQL uses " between tables and columns name

MYSQL uses `

When I use the `:include` option in a MYSQL model, it will try and go read the corresponding results in the MSSQL model table. Since the NoClient link field comes from my MYSQL model, it gets mixed and MSSQL throws an error which is logical.

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

CLIENT MODEL (MSSQL Database)

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base  
  establish_connection "mssql_#{RAILS_ENV}"  
  set_table_name "viewInfoClient"  
  set_primary_key "NoClient"  
  has_many :billets, :foreign_key => 'noclient', :primary_key => 'NoClient'
end
```

BILLET MODEL (MySQL Database)

```
class Billet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => 'noclient'
end
```

AFFECTED STATEMENT
Could be anything using :include in it between the 2.
Example from the Billet model

```
def findall
  find(:all, :include => 'client', :conditions => 'bin_id = 1')
end
```

Will return:

```
SELECT * FROM "viewInfoClient" WHERE ("viewInfoClient".`NoClient` IN (6044196,5000652,0204392))
```

Where `(6044196,5000652,0204392)` are the 3 records that have `bin_id = 1` in the `Billet` model.

I remove everything else from my models to shorten the code, but this is it basically. I can reproduce it from any model that uses a MySQL - MSSQL link.

Comment: Can you post one of the affected find statements, the SQL it generates, and the two model classes you're operating on?

Comment: Hello Sarah, I added more code, examples, the models and the results for you to check. Thanks

Comment: If someone know the answer of this, I posted a couple weeks ago, but i'm still looking for the answer! Thanks